# Connecting Nexmo to a Websocket fails(remote party closed the WebSocket) in .Net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, websocket, phone-call, vonage

I'm trying to connect **Nexmo** to a web socket when doing an inbound call (the user calls the number bought with nexmo and link to the app).

As of now, I'm simply trying this [Sample Code](https://github.com/aspnet/Docs/tree/master/aspnetcore/fundamentals/websockets/samples) (which simply echoes back what the caller says) and to connect to this websocket via Nexmo following the "documentation" [Here](https://developer.nexmo.com/voice/voice-api/guides/websockets).

I successfully send an action "connect" to nexmo. While calling the number bought with Nexmo, it properly redirects to the endpoint (`api/nexmo/socket`), as shown when using breakpoints, but then it hangs up when reaching **webSocket.ReceiveAsync** in the Echo method.

```
    using System;
    using System.Net.WebSockets;
    using System.Threading;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
    using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

    namespace MyProject.Web.Controllers
    {
        [Route("api/[controller]")]
        [ApiController]
        public class NexmoController : ControllerBase
        {
            private WebSocket _webSocket;

            [HttpGet("answer")]
            public IActionResult AnswerHandler()
            {
                const string host = "MY_NGROK_URL";
                const string locale = "fr-FR";

                var nccos = new JArray();
                var nccoConnect = new JObject()
                {
                    { "action", "connect" },
                    { "endpoint", new JArray(new JObject{
                            { "type", "websocket" },
                            { "uri", $"wss://{host}/api/nexmo/socket"},
                            { "content-type", "audio/l16;rate=16000"},
                            { "headers", new JObject {
                                    { "language", locale },
                                    { "callerID", "MY_NUMBER_HARDCODED_WHILE_TESTING" }
                                }
                            }
                        })
                    }
                };
                nccos.Add(nccoConnect);
                return Content(nccos.ToString(), "application/json");
            }

            [HttpPost("event")]
            public IActionResult EventHandler()
            {
                return Ok();
            }

            [HttpGet("socket")]
            public async Task GetAudio()
            {
                if (HttpContext.WebSockets.IsWebSocketRequest)
                {
                    _webSocket = await HttpContext.WebSockets.AcceptWebSocketAsync();
                    await Echo(HttpContext, _webSocket);
                }
                else
                {
                    HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 400;
                }
            }

            //Copy Paste from the Sample Code
            private async Task Echo(HttpContext context, WebSocket webSocket)
            {
                var buffer = new byte[1024 * 4];
                //Breakpoint : ReceiveAsync generates an exception
                WebSocketReceiveResult result = await webSocket.ReceiveAsync(new ArraySegment<byte>(buffer), CancellationToken.None);
                while (!result.CloseStatus.HasValue)
                {
                    await webSocket.SendAsync(new ArraySegment<byte>(buffer, 0, result.Count), result.MessageType, result.EndOfMessage, CancellationToken.None);

                    result = await webSocket.ReceiveAsync(new ArraySegment<byte>(buffer), CancellationToken.None);
                }
                await webSocket.CloseAsync(result.CloseStatus.Value, result.CloseStatusDescription, CancellationToken.None);
            }
        }
    }
```

Here the exception that was caught :

> System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketException (0x80004005): The remote
>   party closed the WebSocket connection without completing the close
>   handshake. ---> System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketException (0x80004005):
>   The remote party closed the WebSocket connection without completing
>   the close handshake.

More of the exception:

> at System.Net.WebSockets.ManagedWebSocket.ThrowIfEOFUnexpected(Boolean
>   throwOnPrematureClosure)
>   at System.Net.WebSockets.ManagedWebSocket.EnsureBufferContainsAsync(Int32
>   minimumRequiredBytes, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Boolean
>   throwOnPrematureClosure)
>   at System.Net.WebSockets.ManagedWebSocket.ReceiveAsyncPrivate[TWebSocketReceiveResultGetter,TWebSocketReceiveResult](`` Memory`1 `` 
>   payloadBuffer, CancellationToken cancellationToken,
>   TWebSocketReceiveResultGetter resultGetter)    at
>   System.Net.WebSockets.ManagedWebSocket.ReceiveAsyncPrivate[TWebSocketReceiveResultGetter,TWebSocketReceiveResult](`` Memory`1 ``
>   payloadBuffer, CancellationToken cancellationToken,
>   TWebSocketReceiveResultGetter resultGetter)    at
>   ....Controllers.NexmoController.Echo(HttpContext context,
>   WebSocket webSocket) in
>   C:...\Controllers\NexmoController.cs:line
>   97    at ....Controllers.NexmoController.GetAudio() in
>   C:...\Controllers\NexmoController.cs:line
>   68    at lambda_method(Closure , Object )    at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.ObjectMethodExecutorAwaitable.Awaiter.GetResult()
>   at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ActionMethodExecutor.AwaitableResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper
>   mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[]
>   arguments)    at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1.get_Result()    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodAsync()
>   at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeNextActionFilterAsync()
>   at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContext
>   context)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State&
>   next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
>   at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeNextResourceFilter()
>   at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContext
>   context)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next,
>   Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()
>   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeAsync()
>   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
>   httpContext)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointRoutingMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
>   httpContext)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
>   context)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
>   context)

Any ideas what went down? Or how I could fix this?
I don't really understand what's the issue here.

I also tried to check the WebSocketState of the Websocket and it is set on "Open".
For info, I tested the sample code (websocket echoing the user's input) on its own and it works.

Comment: Can you log what you're trying to echo back? It could be that you're echoing back a textual message and not audio. See https://developer.nexmo.com/voice/voice-api/guides/websockets#first-message

Comment: I was using only audio input only so that's not it :) but in the end we've found the problem : ngrok (see answer below) :) still thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We've found a solution :

- **ngrock** doesn't work with websockets (not without a fee), so we published our app on azure.
- We needed to instantiate the websocket in
  the **StartUp** and not in our controller (like the [sample code
  listed in the original post](https://github.com/aspnet/Docs/tree/master/aspnetcore/fundamentals/websockets/samples)). We've put the "Echo" method in
  another class (more so to keep a good structure) and set it has
  static.

Now everything works :)

Clarification : **ngrock** doesn't work with secured websockets (wss)

Comment: Do you have a link ngrok restriction? I can't see anything in their pricing https://ngrok.com/pricing or documentation https://ngrok.com/docs#websockets

Comment: when doing the command : "ngrok tls" (since we want to use secure websockets wss), we get this messages :
"Tunnel session failed: Only Pro & Business plans may bind TLS tunnels.
Failed to bind a TLS tunnel for the account 'redacted'.
This account is on the 'Free' plan.

Upgrade to Pro or Business: https://dashboard.ngrok.com/billing/plan

ERR_NGROK_312". Switching to publishing our app worked :)